# Css aligning elements inside a flex <div> to fill the bottom as priority when elements wrap

Tags: css, web, flexbox, alignment

What I have is this. A div with some divs inside. The other div has display: flex and flex-wrap: wrap. The dis inside all have a width of 20. now everything is laid ok in large screen as its all flat. but when the screen size shrinks the last divs go to the bottom as it should be.

[image: Divs inside a flex div]

However my use case needs me to have it move with all seemingly falling to the bottom (not sticking to the top. I need "These" to remain on top but the rest ("are", "some", "divs") would fall to the bottom automatically.

[image]

is this even possible with plain css?

Comment: You can almost get there by setting `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse` It will not fall down but it will start in the bottom and wrap upwards instead of down.

Comment: yup this gets us almost there. Just the order does not follow

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 50px;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .sub-container {
    display: flex;
  }

  .item {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
  }
```

there

```
  <div class="sub-conainer">
    <div class="item">are</div>
    <div class="item">some</div>
    <div class="item">divs</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).